# MVVM with async/await API call in Swift

Tags: swift, api, swiftui, concurrency

I've been trying to send the data I receive from my API call to the a view without any success. The idea is that the user enters a license plate number in the HomeView. A sheet view is then instantiated as they press "search", and which should then ideally call on the API with the license plate the user entered appended to the URL. Finally, it should display the vehicle name, model, etc.

I've tried to call the fetchCar() function in the "init" in Vehicle Screen, but it won't allow me because the init() does not support concurrency. I've tried wrapping it in a Task, but then I wont have the vehicle property in the scope.

**The idea is:**

- The user enters a registration number (HomeView).
- A sheet view is instantiated with the user input (VehicleView).
- The sheet view then calls on the API with the user input in order to return the vehicle. The vehicle property is then assign to the fetchCar() call.
  – The sheet view presents relevant information regarding the vehicle.

'

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @State var userInput: String =  ""
    @State var pressedSearch = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Enter license plate number: ")
          
                HStack {
                    TextField("e.g. 27382", text: $userInput)
                
                    Button(action: {
                        self.pressedSearch = true
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Search")
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $pressedSearch, content: {
                        VehicleScreen(licensePlateNumber: userInput)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

'

'

```
struct VehicleScreen: View  {
    @State var licensePlateNumber: String
    @State var vehicle: Vehicle
    @ObservedObject var vm = VehicleViewModel()

    init(licensePlateNumber: String) {
        self.licensePlateNumber = licensePlateNumber
        vehicle = try await vm.fetchCar(regnumber: licensePlateNumber) //'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(vehicle.name)
        }
    }    
}
```

'

'

```
class VehicleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum NetworkError: Error {
        case badURL
        case badStatusCode
        case vehicleNotRegistered
        case illegalFormat
        case decodingError
        case unspecifiedError
        case noData
    }

    func fetchCar(regnumber: String) async throws -> Vehicle {
            guard let url = URL(string: "wwww.example.com/" + regnumber) else {
            throw NetworkError.badURL
            }
        
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["value" : "key"]
        
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                throw NetworkError.badStatusCode
            }
        
            guard response.statusCode == 200 else {
                if response.statusCode == 204 {
                    throw NetworkError.vehicleNotRegistered
                } else if response.statusCode == 400 {
                    throw NetworkError.badURL
                } else if response.statusCode == 422 {
                    throw NetworkError.illegalFormat
                } else {
                    throw NetworkError.unspecifiedError
                }
            }
        
            let car = try JSONDecoder().decode(Vehicle.self, from: data)      
            return car
    }
}
```

'

Comment: 1) Use `@StateObject`, not `@ObservableObject` when the `View` owns the object. 2) You are correct that using `Task` will lead to not having the `Vehicle` immediately -- that is the nature of async. You have to handle the situation where's it isn't available yet. 3) Don't do anything like that inside of `init`. Use `.task { }` in the view body instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the asynchronous request out of the `init` method and into a `task` block, e.g. in `VehicleView` (what you called `VehicleScreen`):

```swift
struct VehicleView: View  {
    let licensePlateNumber: String
    @StateObject var vm = VehicleViewModel()

    init(licensePlateNumber: String) {
        self.licensePlateNumber = licensePlateNumber
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(vm.vehicle?.name ?? "Searching for \(licensePlateNumber)...")
        }.task {
            do {
                try await vm.fetchCar(licensePlateNumber: licensePlateNumber)
            } catch {
                print(error) // you'd presumably do something more meaningful with the error, e.g. update the UI ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And, FWIW, I moved the `Vehicle` into the view model, and make it a `Published` property:

```swift
@MainActor
class VehicleViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var vehicle: Vehicle?

    func fetchCar(licensePlateNumber: String) async throws {
        var request = ...

        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
            throw VehicleError.badStatusCode
        }

        guard response.statusCode == 200 else {
            ...
        }

        vehicle = try JSONDecoder().decode(VehicleResponse.self, from: data).licensePlateLookup   // usually there is some response object and the results of the license lookup is a property of that broader response object
    }
}

extension VehicleViewModel {
    enum VehicleError: Error {
        case badURL
        case badStatusCode
        case vehicleNotRegistered
        case illegalFormat
        case decodingError
        case unspecifiedError
        case noData
    }
}
```